# Should DialogFragment be called through AsyncTask class?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-dialogfragment

I read many guides but I'm still confused.

Somewhere I read that the "activity flow" should not be interrupted by a **DialogFragment**, so you should call DialogFragment inside a **AsyncTask Class** inside the **Activity Class**.

In other guides I saw DialogFragment being called from the Activity Class without using AsyncTask.

So my question is: should DialogFragment be called only through AsyncTask class?

This is the way I did so far; the Activity class code:

```
public class LunchActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
....    
  public void callDialog(){
     class ShowInfoToUser extends AsyncTask<Bundle, Void, Bundle> {                   
        ...
        @Override
        protected Bundle doInBackground(Bundle... args) {
           ...
        }    

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bundle resultBundle) {
            DialogFragment permissionDialogManager= permissionDialogManager.newInstance(messageBundle);
            permissionDialogManager.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "Permission Dialog");
        }    
    }    
}
```

This is the class that extends DialogFragment:

```
public class PermissionDialogManager extends DialogFragment {  

    public static PermissionDialogManager newInstance(Bundle bundle) {
        PermissionDialogManager frag = new PermissionDialogManager();
        frag.setArguments(bundle);
        return frag;
    }    

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code inside AsyncTask's onPostExecute method execute in the UI Thread. In the example you have provided, there is not difference if you use AsynTask or not, because the code will be executed in the UI Thread.

Maybe in the example you have seen, they process some information in the AsyncTask's doInBackground method (that execute in separate thread) and later in the onPostExecute method they use the previous information to invoke the DialogFragment.

How to know when should you run code in the UI Thread?

[Processes and Threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads)

> When your app performs intensive work in response to user interaction, this single thread model can yield poor performance unless you implement your application properly. Specifically, if everything is happening in the UI thread, performing long operations such as network access or database queries will block the whole UI. When the thread is blocked, no events can be dispatched, including drawing events. From the user's perspective, the application appears to hang. Even worse, if the UI thread is blocked for more than a few seconds (about 5 seconds currently) the user is presented with the infamous "application not responding" (ANR) dialog. The user might then decide to quit your application and uninstall it if they are unhappy.

Answer (score 0):

As the Dialog will interrupt the user, I see no reason to put it in an AsyncTask. The dialog is not supposed to take a huge amount of time to generate itself.